# No qt5widgets.dll installed is reason GIS files can not be loaded

Tags: qgis

Original Problem; some GIS files could not be accessed, because no **qt5widgets.dll** installed.  I downloaded **qt5widgets.dll** from DLL-Files.com Client. This crashed QGIS program and I get:

*The procedure entry point: ??0QAbstractTextDocumentLayoutPrivate@@QEAA@XZ could not be located in the dynamic link library Qt5Gui.dll.*
And
*Oops, looks like error loading QGIS. Details: Could not load qgis_app.dll.
Windows Error: the specified procedure could not be found.
Help: check C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.4\bin\qgis-g7.env for correct environmental paths.*

I downloaded new **qt5Gui.dll**, but still same error, even with specific directions to download: Qt5Gui.dll Version 5.11.2.0. (Windows 7 64-bit) to \QGIS 3.4\apps\qt5\bin. Also uninstalled and reinstalled QGIS 3.4.3. No luck.

Is there anything I can do?

Comment: Hi Scott, welcome to GIS SE! I think that for some reason you had to install the qt5widgets library, that you installed it in system32 and that made QGIS not be able to load again. I think you should clarify why you needed to install that library ("some GIS files could not be accessed" does not provide enough information), and if it is correct that you installed it in system32. Please [edit](https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/311630/edit) the body of your question to include the missing information, so we can find the right solution to the original problem.

Answer (score 2):

> You have Qt5 in system32 - that masks the Qt5 that comes with QGIS.  If
>   you removed
>
> c:\windows\system32\QT5GUI.DLL
>   c:\windows\system32\QT5NETWORK.DLL
>   c:\windows\system32\QT5WIDGETS.DLL
>   c:\windows\system32\QT5OPENGL.DLL
>   c:\windows\system32\QT5XML.DLL
>
> QGIS will probably start.

Source: http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/EXT-QGIS-3-4-doesn-t-start-Windows-10-td5385320.html

Also useful: https://issues.qgis.org/issues/19569